# Brent's method wrapped in a while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am attempting to use python 2 to solve a very complicated function that relies on two variables, ne_b and T, using Brent's method with scipy. In order to ensure accuracy of entering the function, I have broken it up into several functions, all of the variable ne_b. For a certain temperature T, I have successfully used Brent's method to find the minimum of the master function f.

Now, I would like to find the solutions of ne_b at f(ne_b) = 0, but for different values of temperature. So I have created an interative loop over 1500 < t_3 < 25000, and listed the exact same functions, only renamed to avoid redundancy, so for each value t_3, a new function of ne_b is calculated.

The entire code:

```
import scipy.optimize as op
from scipy.optimize import fsolve 
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
from scipy.optimize import bisect

#Defining constants for computation.
kB = 8.6173303e-5 # eV/K
k = 1.38065e-16 #dyne * cm / K
a = 7.566e-15 #erg cm^-3 K^-4
Rn = 13.598 #eV
X = 0.71
Y = 0.27
Z = 0.02
me = 9.110e-28 #grams
ma = 1.661e-24 #grams
C = 4.83e15 #Saha constant in cm^-3 K^-3/2
He_1 = 24.5873876 #Ionization potential of helium in eV.
He_2 = 54.4177630 #Ionization potential of ionized helium in eV.
Ca_1 = 6.113158 #ionization potential of neutral calcium in eV.
Ca_2 = 11.87172 #Ionization potential of ionized calcium.
T=[] #Temperature in kelvin. 
#U_11=0 #Partition function for neutral hydrogen.
U_21 = 1. #Partition function for ionized hydrogen.
U_12 = 1. #Partition function for neutral helium.
U_22 = 1.9999 #Partition function for ionized helium.
U_32 = 1. #Partition function of doubly ionized helium.
#U_120=0 #Partition function for neutral calcium.
#U_220=0 #Partition function for ionized calcium.
U_320 = 1. #Partition function for doubly ionized calcium.
P_gas = 100. #dyne cm^-2
A_1 = 1.00790 #Atomic mass of hydrogen.
A_2 = 4.00260 #Atomic mass of helium.
A_20 = 40.08 #Atomic mass of calcium. 
a_1 = float((X/A_1) / ((X/A_1) + (Y/A_2) + (Z/A_20))) 
a_2 = float((Y/A_2) / ((X/A_1) + (Y/A_2) + (Z/A_20)))
a_20 = float((Z/A_20) / ((X/A_1) + (Y/A_2) + (Z/A_20)))
mu_n = float(1. / ((X/A_1) + (Y/A_2) + (Z/A_20)))

#Defining arrays for problem 3 plots. 
N = [] #total number density of gas.
T_3 = [] #Temperature in kelvin.
ne_3 = [] #Brent-solved electron density.


t_3 = 1500 #Kelvin.
while t_3 <= 25000:
    xp20 = [100, 2520, 2800, 3150, 3600, 4200, 5040, 6300, 8400, 12600, 25200]
    fp11 = [1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 1.9999, 2.0091, 2.3334]
    U_11b = np.interp(t_3, xp20, fp11)

    fp120 = [1, 1, 1.0023, 1.0069, 1.02329, 1.06660, 1.183, 1.5171, 2.9174, 21.4783, 172981.636]
    U_120b = np.interp(t_3, xp20, fp120)

    fp220 = [1.9999, 1.9999, 2.0045, 2.0137, 2.037, 2.0893, 2.208, 2.4604, 3.0409, 4.5499, 6.6834]
    U_220b = np.interp(t_3, xp20, fp220) #Partition function of ionized calcium.

    n_3 = (P_gas) / (k*t_3) #Finding total number density.
    N.append(n_3)

    #Neutral hydrogen.
    prod_11b = Rn / (kB * t_3)
    exp_11b = np.exp(-prod_11b)
    def Y_11b(ne_b):
            return (1/ne_b) * (C*t_3**1.5*(U_21 / U_11b)*exp_11b)
    def f_11b(ne_b):
            return (1 + Y_11b(ne_b))**-1

    #Ionized hydrogen.
    def f_21b(ne_b):
            return Y_11b(ne_b) / (1 + Y_11b(ne_b))

    #Neutral helium.
    prod_12b = He_1 / (kB * t_3)
    exp_12b = float(np.exp(-prod_12b))
    def Y_12b(ne_b):
            return (1/ne_b) * (C * t_3**1.5 * (U_22 / U_12) * exp_12b)

    #Ionized helium.
    prod_22b = He_2 / (kB * t_3)
    exp_22b = float(np.exp(-prod_22b))
    def Y_22b(ne_b):
            return (1/ne_b) * (C * t_3**1.5 * (U_32 / U_22) * exp_22b)

    #For neutral helium.
    def f_12b(ne_b):
            return (1 + Y_12b(ne_b) + Y_22b(ne_b)*Y_12b(ne_b))**-1

    #Final ionized helium expression.
    def f_22b(ne_b):
            return Y_12b(ne_b) * (1 + Y_12b(ne_b) + (Y_12b(ne_b) * Y_22b(ne_b)))**-1

    #Doubly ionized helium.
    def f_32b(ne_b):
            return (Y_22b(ne_b) * Y_12b(ne_b)) / (1 + Y_12b(ne_b) + (Y_22b(ne_b) * Y_12b(ne_b)))

    #Neutral calcium.
    prod_120b = Ca_1 / (kB * t_3)
    exp_120b = float(np.exp(-prod_120b))
    def Y_120b(ne_b):
            return (1/ne_b) * (C * t_3**1.5 * (U_220b / U_120b) * exp_120b)

    #Singly ionized calcium.
    prod_220b = Ca_2 / (kB * t_3)

    #For neutral calcium:
    def f_120b(ne_b):
            return (1 + Y_120b(ne_b) + (Y_120b(ne_b) * Y_220b(ne_b)))**-1

    #For ionized calcium.
    def f_220b(ne_b):
            return f_120b(ne_b) * Y_120b(ne_b)

    #Doubly ionized calcium.
    def f_320b(ne_b):
            return f_220b(ne_b) * Y_220b(ne_b)

    #Creating the master sum function.
    def sum(ne_b):
            return (a_1 * f_21b(ne_b)) + (a_2 * (f_22b(ne_b) + 2.*f_32b(ne_b))) + (a_20 * (f_220b(ne_b) + 2.*f_320b(ne_b)))

    #Creating the final function g(ne_b).
    def g(ne_b):
            return ((n_3 - ne_b) * sum(ne_b)) - ne_b

    #Attempting to minimize complicated function using Brent's method.
    #ne_bf = op.minimize_scalar(g, bounds=(1, 1e15), method='brent', tol=1e-08)
    ne_bf = op.brentq(g, -1e15, 1e15) #Just guessing at values, one near total suspected density, one opposite for bounds.
    ne_3.append(ne_bf)

    t_3 = t_3 + 50 #Steps of 50 kelvin.
    T_3.append(t_3)

print "End of code so far."
```

When I run the loop, the error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "hw6.py", line 444, in 
>   ne_bf = float(op.brentq(g, -1e15, 1e15)) #Just guessing at values, one near total suspected density, one opposite for bounds.
>
> File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/optimize/zeros.py", line 415, in brentq
>       r = _zeros._brentq(f,a,b,xtol,rtol,maxiter,args,full_output,disp)
>
> File "hw6.py", line 440, in g
>       return ((n_3 - ne_b) * sum(ne_b)) - ne_b
>
> File "hw6.py", line 436, in sum
>       return (a_1 * f_21b(ne_b)) + (a_2 * (f_22b(ne_b) + 2.*f_32b(ne_b))) + (a_20 * (f_220b(ne_b) + 2.*f_320b(ne_b)))
>
> File "hw6.py", line 384, in f_21b
>       return Y_11b(ne_b) / (1 + Y_11b(ne_b))
>
> File "hw6.py", line 378, in Y_11b
>       return (1/ne_b) * (C*t_3**1.5*(U_21 / U_11b)*exp_11b)
>
> ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

I just need to zero each new function, and append that value to an array for plotting later.

I have tested each of these functions for some random float value like g(12.78432), and they compute separately. It's only when I try to zero each function that I get this error. Any advice is appreciated. I can also provide more information if requested, or the successful code (the one that ran for a discrete value of t_3) if requested. Thank you!

Comment: In addition to @Batman's excellent answer -- if this is an error condition rather than something which is routinely expected to happen, you could wrap the offending code in `try ... except ZeroDivisionError `

Comment: @JohnColeman Why not put this into an answer? While his answer is certainly correct, this is more pythonic than what Batman suggests.

Comment: @sobek For numerical analysis it makes more sense to look before you leap rather than relying on error trapping (which tends to be slower because of stack unwinding). Whether or not my comment is more pythonic in some ways, it is probably inferior in the special case of `numpy`

Comment: @JohnColeman Good point, but then, if performance is that much of an issue for the OP, looping ~500 times in python might not be the way to go anyway (vs. say, vectorization). :-)

Comment: @JohnColeman - It wasn't expected error, since the functions can compute separately with supplied values of ne_b and T. They also work separately when I zero them with Brent's method outside of the loop. I'm wondering if I could just append each function in the temperature look to an array and then act brent's method on each one in the array.

Comment: @JohnColeman - That was a really good suggestion though. Doing that helped me pinpoint problem areas and correct it without having to deal with the global errors, which aren't specific to any point in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to divide by zero. Figure out what you want each function to return if the denominator is zero, probably `None`, `float("Inf")`, or `numpy.nan`. Then have each function check if the denominator is zero *before* it attempts division.

Comment: @ Batman: I'm not using each function to return something, just as a way to properly book-keep all the terms in my master function. However, I did find that I could take each function I created, give it a specific float value, and every function would compute and print the correct numerical value. Separately, they all work, even within the loop. That's why i don't get the zero error.

Comment: Where's the rest of your code. You've got a bunch of variables here like `P_gas`, `Rn`, and `U_32` that aren't defined anywhere.

Comment: It's pretty long, which is why I avoided posting the entire thing to the thread, and now I can't seem to post the rest to comments. I'll edit the original post.